# HTML form query JSON data for matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have to search through some JSON data looking for matches from an input form. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="searchForm" class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="searchText" class="form-control />
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's my JS ...

```
let searchForm = document.getElementById('searchForm');

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let searchText = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
  getCharacters(searchText);
});

function getCharacters(searchText){
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'characters.json', true);
xhr.onload = function(){
if(this.status == 200){
  let characters = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  let output = '';

  for(let i in characters){
    output +=
      ...
;
  }
  document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output;
}
}xhr.onerror = function(){
console.log('Request error');
}xhr.send();
};
```

And my JSON ...

```
[
{
  "id": 1001,
  "first_name": "Rick",
  "last_name": "Grimes",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI2NDYyNjg4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI5OTMwNA@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Sheriff",
  "actor": "Andrew Lincoln",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["rick","grimes","sheriff","andrew","lincoln","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1002,
  "first_name": "Daryl",
  "last_name": "Dixon",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5ODE4NTgzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI0MjAwMw@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "unknown",
  "actor": "Norman Reedus",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["daryl","dixon","unknown","norman","reedus","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1003,
  "first_name": "Glenn",
  "last_name": "Rhee",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxODE2MDgxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjk2MDM1NzE@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Nerd",
  "actor": "Steven Yeun",
  "still_alive": false,
  "tags": ["glenn","rhee","nerd","steven","yeun","dead"]
}
]
```

Within the JS I am looking for a way to use the searchText to query the JSON based on either first_name, last_name or tags. From there I will output the matching data into a div for each match.

Need help with the query part! Everything else I have working but I'm stuck at this point. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest "converting" the JSON into actual JS objects rather than converting the response into an array of chars.  This way, you can associate the matches with their fields, etc. etc. and pretty much do anything with it from that point forward.

Answer (score 0):

First parse it from JSON to JS object then filter it

```
let objectsFromXHR = JSON.parse(`[
{
  "id": 1001,
  "first_name": "Rick",
  "last_name": "Grimes",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI2NDYyNjg4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI5OTMwNA@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Sheriff",
  "actor": "Andrew Lincoln",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["rick","grimes","sheriff","andrew","lincoln","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1002,
  "first_name": "Daryl",
  "last_name": "Dixon",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5ODE4NTgzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI0MjAwMw@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "unknown",
  "actor": "Norman Reedus",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["daryl","dixon","unknown","norman","reedus","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1003,
  "first_name": "Glenn",
  "last_name": "Rhee",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxODE2MDgxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjk2MDM1NzE@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Nerd",
  "actor": "Steven Yeun",
  "still_alive": false,
  "tags": ["glenn","rhee","nerd","steven","yeun","dead"]
}
]`);

const target = 'Glenn'

console.log(objectsFromXHR.filter(each => each.first_name === target));
```

It filter function you can use Regex etc. Just return true to let JS know this currect filtering object is valid

Comment: btw you should give jQuery a try

Comment: There's nothing wrong with standard Javascript, it's OK to write a few more characters (though OP would certainly find it much easier to use `fetch` rather than XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong when you boss don't care about your development speed. There is nothing wrong to spend 1 million dollars to buy a coke. Well, yeah

Answer (score 0):

To search by first and last name, you can combine 2 string and then cast it to lowercase, and then compare with your inputs.

- I added an empty string at the end in case both fields are empty.
- This method is case-insensitive and removes empty inputs in front and end.

```js
const obj = [
{
  "id": 1001,
  "first_name": "Rick",
  "last_name": "Grimes",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI2NDYyNjg4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI5OTMwNA@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Sheriff",
  "actor": "Andrew Lincoln",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["rick","grimes","sheriff","andrew","lincoln","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1002,
  "first_name": "Daryl",
  "last_name": "Dixon",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5ODE4NTgzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI0MjAwMw@@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "unknown",
  "actor": "Norman Reedus",
  "still_alive": true,
  "tags": ["daryl","dixon","unknown","norman","reedus","alive"]
},
{
  "id": 1003,
  "first_name": "Glenn",
  "last_name": "Rhee",
  "img": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxODE2MDgxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjk2MDM1NzE@._V1_.jpg",
  "career": "Nerd",
  "actor": "Steven Yeun",
  "still_alive": false,
  "tags": ["glenn","rhee","nerd","steven","yeun","dead"]
}
];

function searchByName(data, str) {
  return data.filter(i => { 
    const pool = i.first_name + i.last_name + '';
    return pool.toLowerCase().includes(str.trim().toLowerCase());
  });
}

console.log(searchByName(obj, 'Rhe'));
```